# nginx rewrite uppercase to lowercase letters in a rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite url like this:
www.example.com/TeSt/AAA/BBBB ------> www.example.com/test/AAA/BBB

I make like this, but it's not done:

```
location /test {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
location ~* /test/ {
    rewrite .* /test/ last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nginx will select a matching regular expression `location` over a prefix `location` unless the `^~` operator is used. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Your `rewrite` expression needs to be case insensitive, and needs to capture the remaining part of the URI.

For example:

```
location ^~ /test {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
location ~* /test {
    rewrite (?i)^/test(.*)$ /test$1 last;
}
```

Comment: If i want to rewite another rule  https://www.example.com/Test ----> https://www.example.com/test, how can i do ? tks.